# loading large bitmaps at startup

Tags: android, bitmap

I have an intro screen based on this [sample](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-build-intro-slider-app/) but instead of setting colors for background I set an image for each one (I have 3 screens). I have created a drawable folder for each screen density (hdpi etc) and each picture so that I can support multiple sizes and resolutions. Is there anything else I can do or should I do minimize the loading time even more ? Intellij is throwing `Skipped 56 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.`, however, the application is responsive. I was looking at official performance [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html#load-bitmap) but I don't know if it's an overkill to implement it, is placing image assets into various drawable folders enough for this case ? Or should I do those calculations on top of it ? here is what I do now:

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/welcome_image_view"
 android:layout_width="0dp"
 app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
 app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/love"
 android:scaleType="centerCrop"
 tools:ignore="ContentDescription"
 android:layout_height="0dp"
 app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess it's the code you're using to load the images more than your layout file that's causing the frame skipping.

You really have 2 goals.  1st, minimize actual loading time.  Users don't want to start at empty screens or place holders more than they have to.  2nd, move the work off of the UI thread.  Any image loading but the smallest of images shouldn't be done on the UI thread.

For 1, make sure your images aren't any larger than they need to be for display on a device.

For 2, the doc you pointed to recommends [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide).  (Most of the rest of that doc probably doesn't apply to your case.  Much of it is for when you have a full res image but only need to display a thumbnail or other reduced resolution image).  [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is a common way to do simple work off of the UI thread.  (Thread and Runnable are other ways but I won't get into that here).

Comment: thank you for your answer. I figured that the cause of the warning was because even though I had different drawables for different dpis, the size of those images was too big for the UI to handle. I used a tool called tinyjpg.com and compressed my images to about a third of the size and that fixed it. As for your  2nd comment, is using AsyncTask with ViewPagerAdapter a common solution for this task ?

Comment: Yes. Using AsyncTask for image manipulation (or anything else that might require heavy processing) is common in ViewPagerAdapter or elsewhere.  The general rule I learned is to use AsyncTask for things that will take less than 2-3 seconds.  Threads should be used for longer running operations.  One problem with AsyncTask is that screen rotation or other config changes have to be specifically handled.  "Slidenerd" on Youtube shows a way to do this with a Retained Fragment.